# optimize mysql database search with like operator in column contains mobile numbers

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, regexp-like

I have a table with a column that contains mobile numbers, this table has about 40 millions records.
this is the table schema with some dumping data query

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.9.7
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: localhost:3306
-- Generation Time: Jun 08, 2022 at 12:19 PM
-- Server version: 5.7.38-log
-- PHP Version: 7.4.29

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

--
-- Database: `database_name`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `profiles`
--

CREATE TABLE `profiles` (
  `profile_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `birth_date` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `profile_link` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `full_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `employer` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `job` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `facebook_email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `marital_status` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `profiles`
--

INSERT INTO `profiles` (`profile_id`, `mobile`, `birth_date`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `gender`, `profile_link`, `full_name`, `employer`, `job`, `city`, `facebook_email`, `marital_status`) VALUES
('100000000000529', '201226063866', NULL, 'Samer', 'Aly', 'male', 'https://www.facebook.com/samer.Hussein.aly', 'Samer Hussein Aly', NULL, NULL, 'Mansoura', 'samer.Hussein.aly@facebook.com', NULL),
('100000000004160', '201002299054', NULL, 'Sherif', 'Mansour', 'male', 'https://www.facebook.com/sherif.mansour.946', 'Sherif Mansour', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'sherif.mansour.946@facebook.com', 'Married'),
('100000000005840', '201000914451', NULL, 'Moniem', 'Allaban', 'male', 'https://www.facebook.com/moniemvilla', 'Moniem Ayman Allaban', 'Civil Engineers', NULL, 'Sohag', 'moniemvilla@facebook.com', 'Single'),
('100000000006051', '201009975151', NULL, 'Adnan', 'Tahawy', 'male', 'https://www.facebook.com/adnan.tahawy', 'Adnan El Tahawy', 'Allianz Egypt -Head Office', 'Bancasurance', NULL, 'adnan.tahawy@facebook.com', NULL),
('100000000007938', '201282553531', '11/21/1991', 'Alaa', 'Horira', 'male', 'https://www.facebook.com/alaa.logo', 'Alaa Abo Horira', 'شركة الدسوقي جروب لأمهات الدواجن', 'Poultry Production Engineer', 'Giza', 'alaa.logo@facebook.com', 'Single'),
('100000000010755', '201020222026', NULL, 'Ola', 'Abd El-Kader', 'female', 'https://www.facebook.com/ola.eldeeb', 'Ola Abd El-Kader', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'ola.eldeeb@facebook.com', NULL),
('100000000014493', '201001041238', '03/09', 'Sherif', 'Ibrahim', 'male', 'https://www.facebook.com/sherifi', 'Sherif Ibrahim', 'The Arab Contractors (Osman Ahmed Osman & Co)', 'Civil engineer', 'Cairo  Egypt', 'sherifi@facebook.com', NULL),
('100000000023706', '201061016412', NULL, 'Ahmed', 'Ramadan', 'male', 'https://www.facebook.com/ahmed.rando', 'Ahmed Ramadan', 'Dubai Islamic Bank', NULL, 'Ma`Adi  Al Qahirah  Egypt', 'ahmed.rando@facebook.com', NULL),
('100000000026495', '201009909238', '10/01/1993', 'Mohamed', 'Fathy', 'male', 'https://www.facebook.com/mido.strong.mohamed', 'Mohamed Fathy', NULL, NULL, 'Giza', 'mido.strong.mohamed@facebook.com', NULL),
('100000000028259', '201112752668', NULL, 'Saher', 'Galal', 'male', 'https://www.facebook.com/SaherrGalall', 'Saher Galal', 'Nothing', NULL, 'Maddi', 'SaherrGalall@facebook.com', NULL),
('100000000034989', '201225550201', NULL, 'Hytham', 'Omar', 'male', 'https://www.facebook.com/hytham.omar', 'Hytham Omar', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'hytham.omar@facebook.com', 'Married'),
('100000000036425', '201120615833', NULL, 'Youssef', 'Ahmed', 'male', 'https://www.facebook.com/hamada.mody.58910', 'Youssef Ahmed', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'hamada.mody.58910@facebook.com', NULL),
('100000000046485', '201111755011', NULL, 'Dalia', 'El-Shamy', 'female', 'https://www.facebook.com/AMROKAMAL99', 'Dalia El-Shamy', 'Civil Engineering', NULL, 'Helwan', 'AMROKAMAL99@facebook.com', 'Married'),
('100000000048402', '201099407065', NULL, 'Waseem', 'Wafeek', 'male', 'https://www.facebook.com/waseem.wafeek', 'Waseem Wafeek', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'waseem.wafeek@facebook.com', NULL),
('100000000051463', '201002633598', NULL, 'Sabry', 'Nasrala', 'male', 'https://www.facebook.com/sabry.nasrala', 'Sabry Nasrala', 'Diet House', 'Restaurant manager', 'Cairo  Egypt', 'sabry.nasrala@facebook.com', 'Single'),
('100000000053198', '201282832447', '11/14/1968', 'Hatem', 'Moamen', 'male', 'https://www.facebook.com/hatem.moamen', 'Hatem Moamen', 'AOI', 'محاسب', NULL, 'hatem.moamen@facebook.com', 'Married'),
('100000000053761', '201282591776', NULL, 'Bisho', 'Ehab', NULL, 'https://www.facebook.com/bisho.ehab.7', 'Bisho Ehab', NULL, NULL, 'Cairo  Egypt', 'bisho.ehab.7@facebook.com', NULL),
('100000000053907', '201111621168', NULL, 'Mamduh', 'Zakaria', 'male', 'https://www.facebook.com/abofama', 'Mamduh Mohamed Zakaria', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'abofama@facebook.com', NULL),
('100000000054846', '201122930402', NULL, 'Manar', 'Boulad', 'male', 'https://www.facebook.com/manar.boulad.7', 'Manar Boulad', 'Damascus  Syria', NULL, 'Damascus  Syria', 'manar.boulad.7@facebook.com', NULL),
('100000000056063', '201277682638', NULL, 'Kholoud', 'Osama', 'female', 'https://www.facebook.com/kholoud.osama.31', 'Kholoud Osama', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'kholoud.osama.31@facebook.com', NULL),
('100000000058700', '201272298772', NULL, 'Magdi', 'Talat', 'male', 'https://www.facebook.com/magdi.talat', 'Magdi Talat', NULL, NULL, 'Minya  Egypt', 'magdi.talat@facebook.com', 'Married'),
('100000000059048', '201288847174', NULL, 'د. محمد', 'أبوحسين', NULL, 'https://www.facebook.com/100000000059048', 'د. محمد أبوحسين', 'الجهاز المركزي للتنظيم والإدارة', NULL, 'El-Mahmudiya  Al Buhayrah  Egypt', '100000000059048@facebook.com', NULL),
('100000000059243', '201004700599', NULL, 'Ashraf', 'Fathy', 'male', 'https://www.facebook.com/ossoris', 'Ashraf Fathy', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'ossoris@facebook.com', NULL),
('100000000061207', '201002166661', NULL, 'Aisha', 'Abd-Elkader', NULL, 'https://www.facebook.com/toka.mesho', 'Aisha Abd-Elkader', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'toka.mesho@facebook.com', NULL),
('100000000061245', '201119808229', NULL, 'Sara', 'Mohamed', 'male', 'https://www.facebook.com/ahmed.zohdi.3', 'Sara Mohamed', 'farrahtel', NULL, NULL, 'ahmed.zohdi.3@facebook.com', NULL);

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `profiles`
--
ALTER TABLE `profiles`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`profile_id`),
  ADD KEY `profiles_mobile_index` (`mobile`);
COMMIT;
```

I want to search in the table for records like that

```
SELECT profiles.*, coalesce(profiles.mobile, search.mobile) as mobile
from (
        select '2011123123' as mobile
        union all 
            select  '20115434345'
        union all 
            select  '20143534535'
        union all 
            select  '1152840065'
        union all 
            select  '+201152840066'
        union all 
            select  '01152840067'
        union all 
            select  '201152840069'
    ) 
    search
    left join profiles on profiles.mobile like concat('%', search.mobile, '%')
```

i'm using this query like that because
-first need not to loose not found numbers in search result, i want the not found number to come back in the result but with null in all other columns than mobile that's why i used left join with search table that is constructed in runtime with only one column which is the mobile numbers i want to search
-second i used like operator in join clause because some numbers may contain the country code which is 20 for example and others may contain it like that +20 and some others may not contain the country code at all like starting with 011 directly for example, that's why i need the like operator with two wildcards before and after

my question is how to optimize the database to do this query?
will fulltext index in mobile column help ? knowing that the content of mobile column is always one block string i mean like that "0313131231" and not like a paragraph which may has string consists of some words (don't know if fulltext index is character based or word based)
and thank you in advance and sorry for my English language level

Comment: I didn't see you list a case for needing the % wildcard at the _end_; can you explain?

Comment: Start an SQL question by showing the schema for all the relevant tables. Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName;` for each table, and paste it into the questions as text (NOT A PICTURE). 
An example of the data contained in these tables is also very useful, and a view of your expected output based on the table data you show as an example.
If at all possible create a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with the schema defined and some test data provided.

Comment: is profiles.mobile always going to start with the country code?

Comment: Unfortunately, `LIKE '%searchstring%'` is notorious for being difficult to optimize. If you [edit] your question to show us samples of data from your `profiles.mobile` column maybe somebody can help you. Or switch to PostgreSQL and use a trigram index.

Comment: Fulltext indexing will not help for this case, because the pattern must be a fixed string, not a column.

Comment: @ysth yes you are right i don't need the % wildcard at the end i will remove it for improving the query ,,, regarding to the second question yes in database it allways start with country code but there is other countries codes than 20 not always 20 and some times it's 20 but with + before it

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you for this declaration i'm going to do as you said now

Comment: @RiggsFolly i added the sql code for creating the table and dumping some records

Comment: doing create table or alter table immediately commits the current transaction, by the way.

Comment: Is `LEFT` really desired?  Seems like you would get extra junk.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an index on a virtual column containing the phone number reversed:

```
alter table profiles add reverse_mobile varchar(255) as (reverse(mobile)),
    add index reverse_mobile_index (reverse_mobile);

select ...
left join profiles on profiles.reverse_mobile like concat(reverse(search.mobile),'%')
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=cebc32b8bd7cf534c0b120c4b29a15be)

Note that your search will not find numbers with a `+` since that is not in the data.

Comment: thank you my friend for this solution, i tried explain of the select query above after doing these changes and still it filters 100% of the table rows and not sing any indexes, don't know if i'm doing some thing the wrong way

Comment: take a look here my friend [fiddle - explain](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=cb59987f39327f198e2850304f05891c), it's the same result ding explain in the two cases before doing alter and after it

Comment: with so few rows, it won't use the index.  try it with your real data.  possibly you might need index hints, but I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

Cleanse the data and search, if at all possible.  It will allow many more optimization options.

If +20 is the only prefix, get rid of it -- both in the data and the search.  Then the query can be an exact match and you can use `IN` instead of `UNION`.

If it is not always +20, then can you discover the country code and remove it?  What should be done if the country code is missing?